# C# response: {"error":-1, "request":null}

Tags: c#, request, http-headers, http-post

I'm sending a post request to a site. After a while I got this response. And I noticed that the stream returned these errors. 
StreamError:
[image]

My Response Result `{"error":-1,"request":null}`

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; }; 
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestHeader.url);
                request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                request.UserAgent = RandomizerUserAgent();
                request.KeepAlive = requestHeader.keepAlive;
                request.Method = requestHeader.Method;
                request.Referer = RandomizerReferer();
                request.Accept = requestHeader.accept;
                request.Host = requestHeader.Host;
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                request.Proxy = null;
                request.Headers.Add(requestHeader.HeaderReqwith, "XMLHttpRequest");
                string post = "type=email&checkvalue=" + deger + "%40" + globalmail;
                var postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post);
                request.ContentType = requestHeader.contentType;
                request.ContentLength =(long)postBytes.Length;
                using (Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    newStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                    newStream.Flush();
                    newStream.Close();
                }
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                error = false;
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                stream.Dispose();
                reader.Dispose();
                ResponseProcess(result, deger);
```

Comment: Not actual errors, reading is not supported. You have a write-only stream. The length and position are not available (`CanRead` and `CanSeek` are both `false`).

Comment: So what should I do? Should I set it to 'true'?

Comment: What? No. You don't have to do anything. That's the standard Stream returned by `GetRequestStream()`: you can only write to it. Do you mean, you have errors or the POST (I dont' see what `requestHeader.Method` value is set to) doesn't have the expected results? In this case, the WebResponse will return the error or you have an exception, if `HttpStatusCode` is > 399. You should always handle exceptions (`WebException`, at least) when you send a HttpWebRequest: it follows the (ancient) *throw on everything we don't handle* pattern.

Comment: it was working normally. After a while this error came {"error": -1, "request": null}. method post